# Getting href when available

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the `href` data from a `tr`-`td` list (see sample code). But it always returns `null` value. I have tried other methods with `.getElementby...()` but I always bang a wall somewhere.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <p>Click the button to see the 2 results in an alerte box.</p>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
  <table class="list" role="presentation">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><a href="/Parliamentarians/fr/constituencies?sortBy=Name&sortDescending=True">Circonscription</a><span class="icon-ascending"></span></th>
        <th><a href="/Parliamentarians/fr/constituencies?sortBy=Province&sortDescending=False">Province / Territoire</a></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="constituency">
          <a title="Cliquez pour acc&#233;der au profil de la circonscription" href="/Parliamentarians/fr/constituencies/Abbotsford(898)">Abbotsford</a>
        </td>
        <td class="constituency">Colombie-Britannique</td>
        <td class="personName">
          <a title="Cliquez pour acc&#233;der au profil du d&#233;put&#233;" href="/Parliamentarians/fr/members/Ed-Fast(35904)">Fast, Ed  <abbr>(L'hon.)</abbr></a>
        </td>
        <td class="caucus">
          <a target="_blank" title="Site Web du parti politique - Ouvre une nouvelle fen&#234;tre" href="http://www.conservateur.ca">Conservateur</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="constituency">
          <a title="Cliquez pour acc&#233;der au profil de la circonscription" href="/Parliamentarians/fr/constituencies/Abitibi-Baie-James-Nunavik-Eeyou(637)">Abitibi—Baie-James—Nunavik—Eeyou</a>
        </td>
        <td class="constituency">Qu&#233;bec</td>
        <td class="personName">
        </td>
        <td class="caucus">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('.constituency');
      var nodeList2 = document.querySelectorAll('.personName');
      var nodeList3 = document.getElementsByClassName('caucus');

      /* i+=2, because first is circonscription and next is province */
      for (var i = 0, j = 0; i < nodeList.length; i += 2, j++) {
        alert(nodeList[i].innerText + '|' + nodeList[i].getAttribute('href') + '|' + nodeList[i + 1].innerText + '|' + nodeList2[j].innerText + '|' + nodeList2[j].getAttribute('href') + '|' + nodeList3[j].innerText + '|' + nodeList3[j].getAttributeNode('href'));
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Just get the child element of tds with class constituency, then get their href property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The href are attribute of 'a' tag while your code expects to find it on the td/tr.
You are missing one more level deeper in your loop.

```
<td class="constituency">
<!-- note the href on the a tag -->
    <a title="Cliquez pour acc&#233;der au profil de la circonscription" href="/Parliamentarians/fr/constituencies/Abbotsford(898)">Abbotsford</a>
</td>
```

Your javascript code should look like:

```
 nodeList[i].children[0].getAttribute('href')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over the  element which contains  element.

In your for loop you need to insert another for loop which will iterate over [childNodes](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_childnodes.asp), or you can try and skip that and access the A element through [firstChild](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_firstchild.asp) property.

Either way should help you:

```
nodeList3[j].childNodes[0].getAttribute('href')
nodeList3[j].firstChild.getAttribute('href')
```

Comment: Do not know why, but firstChild doesn't work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I think your simplest way forward might be to update your css selector in your javascript to limit by the "first child" of your class selector:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Click the button to see the 2 results in an alerte box.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<table class="list" role="presentation">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><a href="/Parliamentarians/fr/constituencies?sortBy=Name&sortDescending=True">Circonscription</a><span class="icon-ascending"></span></th>            
            <th><a href="/Parliamentarians/fr/constituencies?sortBy=Province&sortDescending=False">Province / Territoire</a></th>            
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="constituency">
                            <a title="Cliquez pour acc&#233;der au profil de la circonscription" href="/Parliamentarians/fr/constituencies/Abbotsford(898)">Abbotsford</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="constituency">Colombie-Britannique</td>
                    <td class="personName">
                            <a title="Cliquez pour acc&#233;der au profil du d&#233;put&#233;" href="/Parliamentarians/fr/members/Ed-Fast(35904)">Fast, Ed  <abbr>(L'hon.)</abbr></a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="caucus">

                            <a target="_blank" title="Site Web du parti politique - Ouvre une nouvelle fen&#234;tre" href="http://www.conservateur.ca">Conservateur</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td class="constituency">
                            <a title="Cliquez pour acc&#233;der au profil de la circonscription" href="/Parliamentarians/fr/constituencies/Abitibi-Baie-James-Nunavik-Eeyou(637)">Abitibi—Baie-James—Nunavik—Eeyou</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="constituency">Qu&#233;bec</td>
                    <td class="personName">
                    </td>
                    <td class="caucus">
                    </td>
                </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('.constituency > a');
    var nodeList2 = document.querySelectorAll('.personName > a');
    var nodeList3 = document.getElementsByClassName('.caucus > a');

    /* i+=2, because first is circonscription and next is province */
    for(var i = 0, j = 0; i < nodeList.length; i+=2, j++ ) {
        alert(nodeList[i].innerText + '|' + nodeList[i].getAttribute('href') + '|' + nodeList[i+1].innerText + '|' + nodeList2[j].innerText + '|' + nodeList2[j].getAttribute('href') + '|' + nodeList3[j].innerText + '|' + nodeList3[j].getAttributeNode('href'));
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could select all `<a>` inside several selectors with `,` in `querySelectorAll`, once you have the elements `.href` to select all url's

```
var nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('.constituency > a, .personName > a, .caucus > a');
for(let i = 0; i<nodeList.length; i++){
console.log(nodeList[i].href);
}
```

Full example here: http://jsfiddle.net/0c2fgdLu/17/